# Simple (?) grails if statement

Tags: grails

So trying to do something (that I think should be simple)
Setting a value further up in the code, then doing a if statement to check what I set it to. 
The piece of code that sets the variable. Copied in below

```
if ( params.headers == null) {
    def headline="1"
    render ("Starting to read on line 1<BR>")
} else {
    def headline="0"
    render ("Skipping line 1<BR>")
}
```

Then a little bit further down in the controller I do the following

```
if ( headline == "0") {
    render "Skipped line for ${fields[0]}"
    headline = "1"
} else {
```

And whenever I run this I get the following error message"

```
No such property: headline for class: regmap.CountryuploadController. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: headline for class: regmap.CountryuploadController
    Line | Method
->>   25 | doCall    in regmap.CountryuploadController$_loadcsv_closure1$$EOrLxdfM
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     34 | eachLine  in org.grails.plugins.csv.CSVReaderUtils
|     47 | eachLine  in     ''
|    140 | doCall    in CsvGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure12
|     22 | loadcsv . in regmap.CountryuploadController$$EOrLxdfM
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Any ideas?
Am clearly missing something, as I even tried to run it after each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are declaring the `headline` variable inside of the `if` and `else` blocks, its scope is limited to those blocks, which is why you get an error when trying to refer to it later.  You want something like this:

```
def headline
if ( params.headers == null) {
    headline="1"
    render ("Starting to read on line 1<BR>")
} else {
    headline="0"
    render ("Skipping line 1<BR>")
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both who answered (even if SteveD deleted his answer). Is this because you can not define new variables inside an if statement?

Comment: You can define new variables inside of an `if` block but if you do they are only accessible from within that block.